# separate a text from database into sentences

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

I need to manage 3 language and 7 different description for each field im accessing my content from.
For example, if i access my area from en/outdoor/Area1 i need to access to "description for Area1 in english according to outdoor"
if i access from fr/outdoor/Area1 i need to accesso to"description for Area2 in french according to outdoor". If i access from fr/house/Area1 i need to access to "description for Area1 in french according to house"
Since the displayed articles are the same for every language i store my description in a language table. And i find this solution: each description of the same language are within the same cell of database separated by a /.
so i can:

fetch data from database according to my {lang}/field/{Area} url then, extract all in an array and then

```
<?php
$Desriptions = 'Description1en~Description2en~Description3en';
$description = preg_split("/~/", $str);
print_r($description);
?>
```

Then, i know that field don't change, and so i can access Area1 according to field 1 in en accessing to database, row en, take all the strin, preg_split, showing for field 1 the 1st one of the split.

Is this a good solution or is better to use another table for this? are there faster ways to do in laravel4?

Comment: Why not change your DB schema to properly store individual language string independently rather than concatenating them together and later splitting them apart?

Comment: I've wrote package to help people store translations in database: https://github.com/antonioribeiro/glottos. As Mike Brant said, you might consider using a different set of tables to store the messages.

Comment: actually, the concatenating string is individual (en) is just that refer to different field. EDIT: my database, already store language in a different table, i just need different description for the same field